# Nginx rewrite last fragment of url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to transform the url 'https://www.example.com/knowledges/qa/123456' to 'https://www.example.com/knowledges/qa.html?id=123456' in `Nginx`.

I'm new to Nginx and try the follw:

```
root   /opt/statics;

location / {            
   index index.html;
}

location /knowledges/qa/ {
   rewrite ([^\/]+)\/?$ /knowledges/qa.html?questionId=$1 last;
}
```

The regex `/([^\/]+)\/?$/g` can match group of the last fragment of url(i.e. 123456).

== Edit ==

Add the last slash `/knowledges/qa/` works. (otherwise dead cycle)

Then, the new question occurs. In `qa.html` retrive the document location:

```
document.location.href // https://www.example.com/knowledges/qa/123456
```

Not the `https://www.example.com/knowledges/qa.html?id=123456` as expected?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: dead cycle. See the update.

Comment: If you have a different question then you should open a new question

Answer (score 0):

I believe `[^/]+` would match `knowledges` not `123456`. Try

```
rewrite ^/knowledges/qa/(\d+)$ /knowledges/qa.html?questionId=$1 last;
```

Comment: The regex `([^\/]+)\/?$` is correct. See https://regex101.com/r/CBuz0o/1/